# How to set environment variables using React and nwb

Tags: reactjs, npm, nwb

I have a component library made with create-react-app where I'm using nwb to serve a demo application to test the components.
Right now the application is served by running the command `nwb serve-react-demo` which starts the demo app with no issues.

I want to simulate different applications using the library. Setting an environment variable directly when running the start up script would be really helpful since I could change the initial state of the application based on which host app was implementing the library. 
If I try to pass an environment variable like this `nwb serve-react-demo REACT_APP_HOST_APPLICATION=AB` the `process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_APPLICATION` variable is undefined.

The [nwb documentation](https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#configuration-via-arguments) states that you can configure the configuration object by passing arguments with the command, but I'm unclear on how to add variables to `process.env` like that.

I'm running macOS 10.15.3

```
from package.js:

"nwb": "0.23.0",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-dom": "16.9.0",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0",
"webpack": "4.41.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being creating one nwb.config.js file for each application,
hardcoding the host application key with webpack define, and then with the --config flag pass the location of each file.

You can find a detailed explanation of my solution [here](https://github.com/insin/nwb/issues/543).